# Why did the "root may not be ready" error keep appearing after restarting Apache IoTDB?

Tags: restart, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why do I keep getting this error when writing data after I restart Apache IoTDB, causing the data writing progress to fail? The error message is: `[ERROR] 2023-09-15 15:44:00,692 [pool-2-thread-9:28321] - method:com.sac.dataarch.common.IotDbOper.getRtData(IotDbOper.java:205) org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 317: the sg root.NXQY.MJTGF may not ready now, please wait and retry later`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that Apache IoTDB is still restarting and restoring its storage. You can write data into IoTDB normally after this recovery process is complete.